# Plesk: free port 80 for other app

Tags: apache-2.2

I have plesk on my web server since it makes setting up emails etc easier.
I want to keep port 8443 for the plesk control panel but i want to free up port 80 to use for another service, so how can i get apache/plesk to either stop listening on port 80 or just listen at a different port.

I am using Plesk 10.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.

i searched for quite some time now and none of the already existent tutorials work for me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the official instructions on how to do it.

http://kb.parallels.com/en/11232

In case you miss it, replace <custom http port> and <custom https port> with the ports you want to use.